# Idiomatic way to implement atomic web service call

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, transactions

I have a webservice that has an action to create some kind of entity.
The method inside the webservice that does the actual work calls several other methods of the webservice. Some of these methods need to access the database to query or update data.

How do I ensure all calls made as part of the web request are part of the same transaction?

### Example

My main method opens a database connection (and transaction). Should I pass the database connection object (and/or transaction object) down to the other methods so they can reuse the existing one instead of opening their own?

I would like to stay as close to what is considered the standard here as possible, but I'm not sure about this scenario as most examples you find only execute a single SQL, typically inside a using block.

In my case I would also use a using block which creates the database connection and inside this block call several other methods passing the database connection. Is this good practise or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a web call that needs to do work in a transaction, you can open a `TransactionScope` in the controller method and call `TransactionScope.Complete()` when all the work is done, as follows:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Do the work, no need to pass the transaction anywhere
    WriteSomethingToTheDatabase();
    WriteSomethingElseToTheDatabase();

    transaction.Complete();
}

public void WriteSomethingToTheDatabase()
{
    // Under the hood, .NET will obtain a connection from the connection pool, and enlist it in the ambient TransactionScope
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        // Assuming Dapper for a simpler example. :)
        connection.Execute(...);
    }
}

public void WriteSomethingElseToTheDatabase()
{
    // Under the hood, .NET will obtain a connection from the connection pool, and enlist it in the ambient TransactionScope
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        // Assuming Dapper for a simpler example. :)
        connection.Execute(...);
    }
}
```

As stated, you don't need to pass the transaction anywhere as it works as an "ambient" transaction. That is to say that any new connection opened in code called here will automatically "enlist" in that transaction anyway. You should always open/close connections for the shortest possible time. Don't worry about passing connections around either because connection pooling is operating under the covers to ensure that the *actual* database connections are handled for you.

Some caveats include:

- Transactions don't work across webservice calls (this should be obvious). So if you open a transaction in a client, then call 2 or more web services via HTTP that do database stuff, any database calls those web services make will not be part of the client's transaction.
- Transactions across different types of databases will end up as "distributed transactions", assuming that's supported by all the database engines involved. MSSQL, MSMQ, RavenDB will all enlist in a single "two-phase commit" transaction. Ideally you want to avoid this, and just have a "local transaction" working across connections to a single database.
- Note that depending on your isolation level, code running in a different transaction (e.g. another web request coming into the server from a different user, executing on a different thread etc) won't be able to see the changes until you commit (via `TransactionScope.Complete()`).

Comment: Thanks alot! Did you mean webservice calls in your first caveat? I will try to use TransactionScope for this, it looks very promising. Of course the question was now downvoted and closed again for being opinion based... but that's the full Stackoverflow experience.

Comment: Ah yes well spotted. I've corrected point one in my answer. I'm not sure "opinion-based" is very helpful, because all software is opinion-based, and many things do obtain a consensus of opinion (i.e. there emerges an idiomatic way of doing things that anyone you asked would agree with), which should mean questions like this with a generally-accepted approach should be allowed. But as you say, it's not StackOverflow if your question doesn't get closed for some stupid reason or another. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I was now able to test this and apparently it is not supported for .NET Core yet? I'm using .NET Core 3.1 und I get the message "This platform does not support distributed transactions", being on Windows using SQL Server. As soon as I create a second sql connection, using the same connectionstring, I get this error.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's upgrading to a distributed transaction, to be honest. On SQL Server newer than SQL Server 2000 it would recognise multiple connections to the same database and not promote them to a distributed transaction. Yes, DTC support has been dropped from .NET Core since it's cross-platform and DTC is strictly a Windows feature.

Comment: Check all the connection strings you're using are EXACTLY the same, so the connection used comes from the same pool. Beyond that, I'm not sure without trying it and working it out for myself.

Comment: I've found the problem. I was opening a new SQLConnection inside the using block of another, because my first method is calling my second method from within that using block. It's working as expected when creating the second connection after the first one was disposed. I wasn't aware of this being done and being a problem, but it makes sense why it's not working then. So this requires some changes in my code as I also use EF and pass my context to some methods, which due to TransactionScope also won't be neccessary anymore. Thanks!